# conditionally reading a block of lines from file in python

Tags: python, io, conditional-statements, readline

I have an address book and would like to print all (possibly multiple) entries,
for a given "last name" efficiently.

The entries have the following structure:

```
Johnsen  
Paul  
First Street  
313  
94134  
State1  
1343154622525  
myemail101@mail.com  

Parker  
Peter  
Scnd Street  
44  
91347  
State2  
1343154622525  
myemail224@mail.com  

...
```

My code so far looks as follows:

```
print("1) Look up by last name")
print("2) Add a person to address book")
print("3) Quit App")

choice = int(input("Enter your choice (1/2/3): "))
if choice == 1:
    lname = input("Enter last name: ")

    addressbook = open("addressbook.txt", "r")

    import itertools
    lnameLines = itertools.islice(addressbook, 0, None, 9)
    matchingLines = []
    lineNumber = 0
    for n in lnameLines:
        if lname.lower() == n.rstrip().lower():
            matchingLines.append(lineNumber)
    lineNumber = lineNumber + 9
print(matchingLines)
```

What this yields, is the starting lines of the matching 9-lines-block to read (incl. white space line).
Now I wonder how to generate and use a sequence that would open the file again and read just the matching blocks for a look up.
I'm pretty sure there is also a more efficient approach to this I'm curious about.

Thanks for help.

Comment: lines aren't very useful... to do this properly, you need actual byte offsets in the file... but maybe look into the `shelve` module, which is a pretty easy (though not perfect) way to do something similar, with some prework...

Answer (score 0):

You could always load the file into a dict where key is l_name and data is everything. I've written a small working portion for you. I would recommend creating a class Address_book that has functionality for loading data, searching, adding data, and writing data back out. It would be simple and straight forward but i'm not going to do everything for you!

```
def load_book(book):
    #assuming your layout never changes

    f = open(book, 'rb').readlines()
    ind = 0

    for i in f:
        if i == '\r\n': #find the empty line seperating each person
            f[ind] = '--'
        ind += 1

    f = [x.split(':') for x in ''.join(f).replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace('  ', ':').lower().split('--')]

    data = {}
    for i in f:
        data[i[0]] = list(x for x in i if i != '')

    return data

def search_book(book, person):
    try:
        return book[person.lower()]
    except:
        for i in book:
            if person.lower() in i:
                return book[i]
        else:
            raise KeyError

book = load_book('add')
print search_book(book, 'Parker')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the your file is small enough to fit into memory, you can store the data in a dict where each last name corresponds to a list of one or more entry:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('test.txt') as f:
    dct = defaultdict(list)
    for block in f.read().split('\n\n'):
        dct[block[:block.find('\n')].strip()].append(block)


def lookup(last_name):
    print('\n\n'.join(dct.get(last_name, [])))


# In [61]: q.lookup('Johnsen')
# Johnsen  
# Paul  
# First Street  
# 313  
# 94134  
# State1  
# 1343154622525  
# myemail101@mail.com
```

test.txt

```
Johnsen  
Paul  
First Street  
313  
94134  
State1  
1343154622525  
myemail101@mail.com  

Parker  
Peter  
Scnd Street  
44  
91347  
State2  
1343154622525  
myemail224@mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your altenative suggestions. I really appreciate the idea of buiding an address book class and also the in-memory approach, though not quite what I need.

My - not the most efficient, but simple - workaround looks like this:

```
choice = int(input("Enter your choice (1/2/3): "))
if choice == 1:
lname = input("Enter last name: ")

book = open("addressbook.txt", "r")

for i, line in enumerate(book):
    if (i % 9 == 0 and 
        lname.lower() == line.rstrip().lower()):
        load = 9
    if load > 0:
        print(line.rstrip())
        load = load - 1
```

Any suggetions regarding avoiding iterating through every line of the textfile are highly appreciated.